# Equivalent of stored procedures for other database systems?

Tags: stored-procedures, rdbms

I am trying to compare centralized, distributed database systems and blockchains in several points and got stuck when searching about 'stored procedures'.

So far, I have thought that this is a general term for scripts that are triggered given a certain event, i.e. the equivalent to 'Smart Contracts' in blockchains. However, I have realized that this term is only used for relational database management systems.

What would be the equivalent to achieve automation within other database systems? I couldn't find anything useful through search engines.

I am trying to find a means to implement some market matching logic (e.g. continuous matching through an order book) into a database system. I thought that would be generally achieved through stored procedures? Or is there another way?

Comment: Stored procedures is not necessarily a means of automation; are you thinkging of triggers? Are you contrasting "distributed" with "relational" databases? Relational databases can be distributed too.

Comment: @mustaccio You got me there! I am actually trying to find means to implement some market matching logic (e.g. continuous matching through an order book) into a database system. I thought that would be generally achieved through stored procedures? Or is there any other way?

Comment: A stored procedure is just one of the endless number of vehicles to deliver program code. Use the one that you are familiar with.